# Is there any possible way to join split string with the same delimeters?

Tags: javascript, join, split

Is there any possible way to join split string with the same delimeters?

For example, I have a string with sentences

```
const str = "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details? PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported! "
```

And I wanna split by sentences. SMth like that.

```
str.split(/[\.?!;]+\s?/g)
```

Can I somehow join that string with the same delimeters?

```
str.split(/[\.?!;]+\s?/g).map(...).join(???)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does the map do (vaguely)?

Comment: why not take the original string?

Comment: @NinaScholz maybe the OP wishes to make edits to the sentence and combine it again with the same delimiters once done?

Comment: The idea is to Create smth like 'To Sentence Case'.
So, we'll have str.split(/[\.?!;]+\s?/g).map(sentence => sentence[0].toUpperCase() + sentence.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(...)

Comment: Camel Case doesn't require splitting by punctuation, don't you just have to split by `' '` and then capitalize first word? Doesn't matter if word is `case` or `case.` or `case?` the `c` will be capitalized

Answer (score 1):

You could split with the delimiters as group and join the string after changing each second part as desired.

```js
const
    str = "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details? PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported! ",
    result = str
        .split(/([\.?!;]+\s*)/) 
        .map((s, i) => s && i % 2 === 0 ? `<stong>${s}<strong>` : s)
        .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `match` to get an array of the delimiters used, then use `reduce` to join the array back and insert the delimiter.

```js
const str = `const str = "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details? PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported! "`
const match = str.match(/[\.?!;]+\s?/g)
const result = str.split(/[\.?!;]+\s?/g).map(e => e).reduce((acc, curr, i) => (acc += curr + (match[i] || ""), acc), "")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do multiple split/joins

```js
let str = "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details? PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported!"

const delim=['.','?','!',';']

delim.forEach(d=>{
  console.log(str.split(new RegExp(`[${d}]+\\s?`))) // showing what split does
  str = str.split(new RegExp(`[${d}]+\\s?`)).map(s=>s).join(d)
})
```

Comment: In that case, I'll rewrite other parts of strings. That's looks bad for me.